# How to change row color in a ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

When I read my DataBase values one by one, I made an if statement and I tried to change row color.
For example if `fark <= 10.000`, my row color is red; if `fark < 0` my row color is black.

I wrote the code above and When I execute it gives me error:

> InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'.
>   Parameter name: index

My code:

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(
    dr[0].ToString());
    lv.SubItems.Add(dr[1].ToString());
    lv.SubItems.Add(dr[2].ToString());
    lv.SubItems.Add(dr[3].ToString());
    lv.SubItems.Add(dr[4].ToString());
    listView1.Items.Add(lv);
    fark = Convert.ToDouble(dr[3].ToString()) - Convert.ToDouble(dr[4].ToString());     

    if (fark <= 10.000) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Near Maximum ");
        listView1.Items[linemum].BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
    else if (fark <= 20.000 && fark >= 10.000) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Maybe Near");
        listView1.Items[linemum].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
    else if (fark < 0) 
    {
      MessageBox.Show("overflow");
      listView1.Items[linemum].BackColor = Color.Black;
    }
    linemum = linemum + 1;
}
```

Comment: CodeProject has lots of samples.  Here is one : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24114/Adding-Color-to-Listview-with-Customdraw

Comment: It is well worth noting that a DataGridView is a better choice for DB related data displays.  It is an actual grid and conditional colors etc is very easy

Comment: You can let the user edit __one__ column only in a listview by setting `LabelEdit=true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, this code is never executed

```
else if (fark < 0) 
{
     //
}
```

because if `fark < 0`, `fark <= 10.000` is true and the statements in this `if` are executed

Secondly, your exception `InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'` means you want to get an item outside the `Items`. For example, if there are 1 elements in your `Items` and you want to get Items[1], it will raise an exception, but Items[0] must work.

Try to init your `linemum = 0` before the loop while